# ORA-01795 with OracleJdbcMessageStore

Tags: spring-integration

I've set up a ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice which "forwards" the payload in case of success (to the log) or failure (back in the messagestore).
While my service is running OK for a while and is correctly polling the configured jdbc channel message store, the following Exception gets thrown after processing 1000 messages..

```
 2018-04-18 09:17:20,427 | ERROR | taskExecutor-1   | session=- user=- | o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler           | org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler            192 | org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID, INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_BYTES from INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE where INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE.GROUP_KEY = ? and INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE.REGION = ? and INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID not in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) order by MESSAGE_PRIORITY DESC NULLS LAST, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:655)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:690)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:717)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore.doPollForMessage(JdbcChannelMessageStore.java:607)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore.pollMessageFromGroup(JdbcChannelMessageStore.java:557)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupQueue.doPoll(MessageGroupQueue.java:318)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupQueue.poll(MessageGroupQueue.java:162)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupQueue.poll(MessageGroupQueue.java:49)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel.doReceive(QueueChannel.java:116)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel.receive(AbstractPollableChannel.java:105)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.receiveMessage(PollingConsumer.java:192)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
 #011at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
 #011at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 #011at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 #011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
 #011at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:698)
 #011at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
 #011... 21 more
```

It looks like there is some kind of caching of message-id's that were allready processed by the Sftp handler. Am I correctly handling the spring integration flow with my [Integration Config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jywq0e8bu3xn5tm/SftpConfig.java?dl=0)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 messageStore.setUsingIdCache(true);
```

See its JavaDocs:

```
 * <p>Consider using this property when polling the database transactionally
 * using multiple parallel threads, meaning when the configured poller is configured
 * using a task executor.</p>
 * <p>The issue is that the {@link #pollMessageFromGroup(Object)} looks for the
 * oldest entry for a giving channel (groupKey) and region ({@link #setRegion(String)}).
 * If you do that with multiple threads and you are using transactions, other
 * threads may be waiting for that same locked row.</p>
 * <p>If using the provided {@link OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider}, don't set {@link #usingIdCache}
 * to true, as the Oracle query will ignore locked rows.</p>
```

That `1000` limit bubbles from this query:

```
public String getPriorityPollFromGroupExcludeIdsQuery() {
    return "SELECT %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID, %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_BYTES from %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE " +
            "where %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.GROUP_KEY = :group_key and %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.REGION = :region " +
            "and %PREFIX%CHANNEL_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_ID not in (:message_ids) " +
            "order by MESSAGE_PRIORITY DESC NULLS LAST, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED";
}
```

Pay attention to the `not in (:message_ids)`. That is where Oracle limits us with `1000`: http://dbaparadise.com/2016/07/limitations-of-the-in-clause-in-oracle-ora-01795/

Comment: Grazie Artem, that was it... But I still don't understand why the rows are still locked after the processing is successfully finished...

Comment: Hm. That can't be. The raw has to be removed from the DB. Try configure `TransactionInterceptor` for the `PollerMetadata.setAdviceChain()`